# Silverlight Custom TabItem?

Tags: silverlight, custom-controls, tabitem

I tried to create a custom tabitem on Silverlight, but when i run it, it's complaining Unable to cast CustomTab to TabItem.

I am not sure how to fix that, any idea?

Thanks alot

Comment: Does CustomTab inherit from TabItem? Would also be worth showing the code

Comment: What is the reasoning for extending TabItem?  What behavior do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Your custom tab item should inherit TabItem. You can simply create a class that inherits TabItem and extend its functionality, but if you'd like to create your own custom styles for the new control as well, you can make it a "Templated Control". This will allow you to inherit TabItem, and define a default control template using Generic.xaml.